# How to lock CD/DVD for particular time period?

Tags: asp.net

i have developed windows application which is c# based and i also dumped my application in cd and dvd.
Now my client requirement is he want lock the cd or dvd for 1 year period after 1 year that cd will not work.
so can you please suggest is der any way to lock the cd for time defined time frame.

Thanks

Comment: Given that you cannot create self destructing DVDs you would implement this in the software you are (presumably) distributing, E.g. [How to make software expire on a certain date on Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211817/how-to-make-software-expire-on-a-certain-date-on-windows) and many other dups

Answer (score 0):

As per @Alex k Comment 
**you can't write CD/DVD with self remove or auto erase because its read only media** 
but you need to implement login in your application and check date/year using your application .

But if if user change his system DateTime then your application may cracked :)
so, best way to create serial no. and validate with your web/remote system .

- Generate yourself a secret key for the product
- Take the user's name
- Concatentate the users name and the secret key and hash with (for example) SHA1
- Unpack the SHA1 hash as an alphanumeric string. This is the individual user's "Product Key"
- Within the program, do the same hash, and compare with the product key online. If equal, OK.