# Copy Protection (mac apps): most cost effective solution?

Tags: cocoa, macos, copy-protection

... after having just read http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?CocoaInsecurity ...

I am curious to know about your experiences with copy protection solutions for protecting macintosh applications.
Is it worth investing *any* time in at all?
OR 
Is it worth investing money in a commercial solution? (& if so, which?)

please consider in your answers:

1) How convenient (or INCONVENIENT) is the solution for the (legal) end user?

2) Does the solution have any effect on the real-time performance of the software (CPU hit?)

3) does the solution incur copy-protection related support incidents?

thx->adv,

|K<

Comment: It seems the first link moved to http://cocoadev.com/CocoaInsecurity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check this related question: [What copy protection technique do you use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/515020/what-copy-protection-technique-do-you-use)

You can also take a look at this blog article: [My Product Registration Solution](http://mere-mortal-software.com/blog/details.php?d=2008-03-10).

Comment: yes, thank you.  I like your answer there. which leads me to edit my question a bit...  regarding support(!!)

Answer (score 0):

**EVERY** approach is inconvenient for the legal end user and **MOST** will be hacked at some point anyway (assuming anybody is interested in the app).

Given the rising popularity of the **Mac App Store** and users becoming rapidly accustomed to it our experience is that they're at the same time less understanding when it comes to the hassle that every copy protection scheme involves.

[Matt's blog article](http://mattgemmell.com/2012/08/24/releasing-outside-the-app-store/) has a nice pros/cons list on the topic of selling through the MAS and coming up with your own copy protection scheme.